# The usage of since with past simple

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

I' ve got a specific sentence I would like to ask about.

"Since 2009 she worked there."
The person doesn' t work there anymore, someone else does, but I refer to a specific period of time in the past that is over. Can past simple be used here?

Thank you

Comment: Related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time

Comment: Related, and see Peter Shor's answer - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327556/since-she-had-given-up-smoking-or-since-she-gave-up-smoking.

Comment: Related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344176/since-present-perfect. The research cited in this question seems to answer yours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For sure, but qualify your dates: "from 2009 to December 2016 she worked there".

Comment: Thank you. I don' t know when that period ended, it' s just written (in Polish
) : "Since 2009 someone worked somewhere. Now (I don' t know the year when she began) someone else works there.

Comment: Then I would say that this person "worked at the establishment from (not since) 2009". If your interviewer then asks further questions, you can quite safely say that you are no longer in touch.  I hope that helps!

Comment: You're very welcome! Please give me an upvote if you are able - it will increase both of our reputations... 

Comment: Sure, but it displays a message: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: No worries - I'm really pleased that I was able to help! 

Comment: I'm sorry, Anonymous. How can this be an answer to 'The usage of since with past simple'? As it stands, neither question nor answer is appropriate on ELU. Without basic research, I doubt the question would be acceptable on ELL, which is for more basic questions.

Comment: Well, we were happy with the state of affairs, until just now! Past simple: my friend worked here since 2009. Problem solved?